# trying check if sql table value already exists before inserting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a basic table with an id column and a location name column. I also have an html form where a user can insert a new location into the table. Before inserting I want to check if my locations table already includes a location name and if it does exist I want to alert the user. If not it will be inserted into the table. First I query the locations table and then I try to use an if statement to see if the input value already matches a location name in my table. But I can't get it to work. My insert code works fine on it's own but I just can't get the conditions working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// add a new location
$("#btn-locationAdd").on("click", function() {
    var addLocationName = $("#addLocationName");

        $.ajax({
            url: 'libs/php/getAllLocations.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {

                for (let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                    
                    if (result.data[i].name === addLocationName.val()) {
                        alert('This location aready exists')
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        $.ajax({
                                url: 'libs/php/insertLocation.php',
                                method: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                data: {
                                    addLocationName: addLocationName.val(),
                                }, 
                                success: function (result) {
                                    $("#addNewLocationModal").modal('hide');
                                    const newLocation = $("#alertTxt").html('New Location Record Created');
                                    alertModal(newLocation);
                                    
                                }
                            }); 
                    }
```

this is the array I get after I query the locations table and get all locations in the table:

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": "200",
    "name": "ok",
    "description": "success",
    "returnedIn": "1.5790462493896E-6 ms"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "London"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "New York"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Paris"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Munich"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Rome"
    }
  ]
}
```

my html:

```
<!-- Add Location Modal -->
        <div id="addNewLocationModal" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h2 class="modal-title">Add New Location</h2>
                    </div>
    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location Name" id="addLocationName"><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" id="btn-locationAdd" value="Add Location" class="btn btn-success">
                        <input type="button" id="btn-addLocationCancel" value="CANCEL" data-bs-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please use ```$("#addLocationName").val();``` to get the value of input element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#btn-locationAdd").on("click", function () {
    var addLocationName = $("#addLocationName");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'libs/php/getAllLocations.php',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            let existed = false;
            for (let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {

                if (result.data[i].name === addLocationName.val()) {
                    existed = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if(existed){
                alert('This location aready exists')
                return 
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: 'libs/php/insertLocation.php',
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    addLocationName: addLocationName.val(),
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $("#addNewLocationModal").modal('hide');
                    const newLocation = $("#alertTxt").html('New Location Record Created');
                    alertModal(newLocation);

                }
            });

        }
    })
})
```